# Android: Volley HTTP Patch Request

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection, android-volley

I just started porting from my existing network library to Android's Volley. So far I have successfully implemented Volleys ImageLoader where applicable. Now, I am trying to get my first http call up and running, but am finding this error.

Note: I intentionally started with a PATCH request because I will be using them frequently. Also, my version of Volley DOES support patch:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/Request.java
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HurlStack.java

**Stacktrace:**

```
E/InputDialogFragment(27940): VolleyError: java.net.ProtocolException: Connection already established
D/Volley  (27940): [1] MarkerLog.finish: (67   ms) [ ] https://mobile.example.com/m/api/v1/user/ 0xb33a3c8d NORMAL 2
D/Volley  (27940): [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [ 1] add-to-queue
D/Volley  (27940): [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [544] cache-queue-take
D/Volley  (27940): [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [544] cache-miss
D/Volley  (27940): [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [545] network-queue-take
D/Volley  (27940): [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+14  ) [545] post-error
D/Volley  (27940): [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+53  ) [ 1] done
```

**PATCH Request**

```
    HashMap<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    values.put(mParam, val);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PATCH, APIConstants.URL_USER, new JSONObject(values),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
               // Blah do stuff here 
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Log.e(TAG, "VolleyError: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                VolleySingleton.getInstance().addCookie(headers);
                return headers;
            }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);
```

Yes, I plan to eventually build out classes for StringRequest, JsonObjectRequest, etc... but currently I just want to get one up and running.

Also, if you are wondering about addCookie, for now I prefer to save my cookie in preferences as I am not as familiar with CookieManager.

**VolleySingleton**

```
public class VolleySingleton {
    private static final String COOKIE_KEY = "Cookie";
    private static VolleySingleton mInstance = null;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private VolleySingleton(){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext());
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                mCache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return mCache.get(url);
            }
        });
        mPreferences = MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(PrefConstants.PREFERENCES, 0);
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        return this.mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public final void addCookie(Map<String, String> headers) {
        String cookie = mPreferences.getString(PrefConstants.PREF_COOKIE, null);
        if(cookie != null){
            headers.put(COOKIE_KEY, cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Noticed that GET and POST are working as expected, so this might only be a Patch issue

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

Volleys HurlStack (HttpUrlConnection) does have supporting code for PATCH. However, it appears to still throw the exception posted in my title and stacktrace whenever you try to issue a PATCH request.

**Hack solution:**

1) Force Volley to use HttpClientStack.

Below is an updated version of my VolleySingleton constructor. This 'works', but clearly wastes the Hurl implementation which is considered better if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9). Not too mention Google plans to move on from the apache HttpClient altogether in future.

```
private VolleySingleton(){
    mPreferences = MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(PrefConstants.PREFERENCES, 0);

    String userAgent = "volley/0";
    try {
        String packageName = MyApplication.getAppContext().getPackageName();
        PackageInfo info = MyApplication.getAppContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
        userAgent = packageName + "/" + info.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {}

    HttpStack httpStack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext(), httpStack);
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mCache.get(url);
        }
    });
}
```

2) Continue to use the above VolleySingleton ONLY for patch; rename it VolleySingletonPatch() and then of course create a Default VolleySingleton() for ALL other NON-PATCH calls. (better than 1, but still not optimal)

3) Solve the exception being thrown in HurlStack despite the fact that Volley has implemented PATCH. This would be BEST, but I prefer to avoid tinkering with Volley directly or extending my own HttpStacks unnecessarily.

I am leaving this unanswered as I would greatly appreciate any insight and of course better options than the ones I have come up with here.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, my solution was to just give up on the underlying inbuilt Apache HTTP components and use OkHttp library from Square using [this `HttpStack` implementation](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899) for Volley that uses OkHttp as its transport. Works great.

Comment: Hello @akent, Do you mind to share how to actually use the implementation in your class?  I mean I followed the link and all, and added the OkHttp library, and also added the `Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), new OkHttpStack());` before `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sendData);`.  Is this correct?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but providing solution could help someone who is yet to encounter same challenge

```
JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    try {
        param.put(KEY 1, VALUE 1);
        param.put(KEY 2, VALUE 2);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        //ID represents the id for the record to update
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PATCH, YOUR URL+ "?ID=" + ID, param,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                 //call handler to display response (optional)

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //call handler to display response (optional)

        }

    }) {

        //            Passing header
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("x-api-key", "YOUR API KEY");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

           //use this to check positive response code returned else remove this override part

            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
    //and then you pass json data to volley
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```